# Show line number of `__builtin_memset` overflow warning

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

In compiling a source file, I recently encountered the following:

```
file.c: In function ‘reader’:
cc1: error: ‘__builtin_memset’ writing 4096 bytes into a region of size 256 overflows the destination [-Werror=stringop-overflow=]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [Makefile.rules:150: file.o] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:388: channels] Error 2
```

Unlike all `gcc` errors I'm used to seeing, this contains no line number or any information at all as to where the issue is, besides the function name.

There are only 2 buffers of size 256 in that function and increasing either of them to 4096 doesn't seem to make any difference. Commenting out the call to `memset` in this function doesn't help, either, so this seemed rather peculiar to me. 4096 doesn't even appear in the source file at all.

Why is gcc not showing me any line number and code context as it typically does, and how can I make it do so? I'm wondering since this is quite late in the compile sequence, given that it says `cc1`, if that information is somehow unavailable. Adding `-Werror=stringop-overflow` to my CFLAGS didn't seem to make it show up earlier, either.

Comment: You should probably show the reader function or we’re just left guessing.

Comment: It's not a concise function, so for the purposes of this question, I'm more interested in how I can track the issue using gcc on my own rather than being told what it might be. However, this happens even with all calls to `memset` in the function commented out, so it's rather odd.

Comment: Note that calls to __builtin_memset can be generated by the compiler for cases other than explicit calls to memset/bzero, hence the suggestion that we might be able to see the offending code.

Comment: I understand that, I'm more curious about how to get gcc to show me where the issue is than the particular issue itself, per se. That way if this happens again, I have a solution in hand

Comment: All right, well this doesn't answer the question, but it looks like the offending code was `FD_ZERO(fds);`. I just brute force commented out different code until I isolated the error. I guess that might make sense, given that `select` can only operate on a limited number of file descriptors, so `gcc` must have something internally built in to detect this. This is definitely the least helpful gcc warning I've ever encountered, but if anyone finds this, that may be the issue